# Custom Jackson JSON serialization based on parent context

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to conditionally serialize a child bean based on information from the parent.

```
public class Parent {
  private boolean isSecure;
  private Child child;
}

public class Child {
  String someValue;
}
```

Basically, if the `parent.isSecure()` is true, then I want to serialize the `someValue` differently than if `parent.isSecure()` is false.

My actual classes are much more complex than this simple example, so I don't really want to create a full custom serializer for `Parent` that I would need to maintain separately (unless you can show me how to leverage standard serialization for `Parent` within the custom serializer without having to iterate through all the properties and deal with JSON annotations, views, and such.  If you can, that might work, as I could set a context attribute based on `isSecure()`).

I don't mind writing a custom serializer for a child, but I don't know how to check the value from the parent.

I've considered using a 'secure' view and 'insecure' view that I could specify outside the entire serialization process, but then I would have to go through and annotate lots of properties of the parent class to be in both the 'secure' and 'insecure' view (as I have turned off the `DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` option due to a number of properties I never want to be serialized).

I tried to access `generator.getCurrentValue()` within my custom Child serializer, but it is always null, so I'm not sure how it is supposed to work.

I've considered writing a custom serializer for `isSecure`, and setting a context attribute within it, but how can I be sure that it will be called prior to the custom serializer for a child? (Though I will admit that I'm not sure context attributes really work the way I am assuming.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a serializer specific to your `isSecure` scenario. Using `JsonGenerator#getCurrentValue` inside of a child element will return the parent. Something like this should allow you to control serialization of `Child` without having to modify the serialization of the other properties on `Parent`.

### Create a `Child` serializer to check the `Parent` property

*`SecureChildSerializer` and `InsecureChildSerializer` are meant to be implementations of `JsonSerializer<Child>`*

```
public class IsSecureChildSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Child> {
    private static final SecureChildSerializer SECURE_CHILD_SERIALIZER = new SecureChildSerializer();
    private static final InsecureChildSerializer INSECURE_CHILD_SERIALIZER = new InsecureChildSerializer();

    @Override
    public void serialize(Child value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (gen.getCurrentValue() instanceof Parent) {
            Parent parent = (Parent) gen.getCurrentValue();
            if (parent.isSecure) {
                SECURE_CHILD_SERIALIZER.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
            } else {
                INSECURE_CHILD_SERIALIZER.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Apply the `Child` serializer to properties of concern

```
public class Parent {
    public boolean isSecure;

    @JsonSerialize(using = IsSecureChildSerializer.class)
    public Child child;
}
```

Comment: I tried calling gen.getCurrentValue(), but it always returns null.  Even looking through the debugger, I can go up the entire writeContext heirarchy, and every _currentValue is null.

Comment: @DavidA how are you registering the serializer? On the property or the ObjectMapper

Comment: I specified the serializer via @JsonSerialize(using = ChildSerializer.class).  Do I need to do some additional registration?

Comment: nope, not what I thought.  Still at a loss as to why currentValue is null.

Comment: Are you annotating the property or the class?

Comment: The property.  My actual code is:   
@JsonSerialize(using = ContentBlocksSerializer.class)
protected List<ContentBlock> contentBlocks;

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce the issue even with the elements in a List. Does `gen.getOutputContext().getCurrentValue()` also fail? I'm going to guess your OutputContext is null for some reason...

Comment: gen.getOutputContexT().getCurrentValue() returns a null, but the output context does exist, and it is populated with names, but no values:  http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1GyHY5bbtOCRYgM3v2969PQnS1CToz

Comment: It's showing a currentName of unitDTOs, I believe that corresponds to the property being written. For some reason is your serializer being hit for multiple classes? Ahh it may be type erasure, if your serializer has List<...> it will use that serializer for all lists? Try checking an element for ContentBlock type first.

Comment: Since it's a List it's a different problem, you may want to consider making a wrapper class so that you can make a serializer specific to that class and not override all List parsing.

Comment: I went the other direction and made a custom serializer for the value stored in the list, but the currentValue is still always null.  I am going to assume I simply cannot use currentValue to solve this issue in my situation.

Comment: I can confirm that in my case `gen.getCurrentValue()` does return the parent object and I was able to customise the serialization based on the parent class.

Comment: Additional note is that you need to call `gen.getCurrentValue()` before your first call to `jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();` otherwise, it will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full length of your design, but IMHO I think this suggests a bit of a problem in the design. If the objects are parsed differently, it means they are essentially different - in that case, why not separate them by inheritance? One way to this would be:

```
    public class Parent {
        private Child child;
    }

    public class SecureChild extends Parent {
        String someValue;
    }

    public class InSecureChild extends Parent {
        String someValue;
    }
```

Comment: The class structure multi-level composition, not inheritance or aggregation, so this is not an option.